# how to get google oAuth token without user login and consent

Tags: oauth, google-api, web-api-testing, google-oauth

is there any way to get google OAuth token without user login and give consent in the google account.
I have my app client id and secret key and other info and have it working using google OAuth offline refresh token procedure, but for that user need to give consent at least once by login using their credentials.

is there any way we can do that without user interaction at all?
(assuming I have user google login credentials ).

Comment: No, otherwise it would be a security issue. User needs to consent that your app will have access to his/her google account and permissions your app have.

Comment: this for CI testing for the app by myself..for actual users the app is getting consent through google login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can a be done using Selenium UI tests.